# Ngram model and smoothing algorithm

Tags: nlp, n-gram

Which smoothing algorithm is easy and effective in case of implementation point of view?

My training corpus is a hex dump looks like,

```
64 FA EB 63 31 D2 62 22 19 BD 64 B5 63 17 4F 48 62 A8 64 11 0F 62 15 9B 64 9B 1F E1 63 62 BE 63
```

I would like to build a 2,3,4,5-gram language model on it. And eventually I need smoothing! Which smoothing algorithm will be suitable and will be easy to implement in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Laplace (add-one) [smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#Smoothing_techniques) should be easy to implement. When it comes to robustness, most n-gram tools (KenLM, SRILM, ...) will default to [Kneser-Ney smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%E2%80%93Ney_smoothing).

For an overview of the performance of different smoothing techniques, see http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P/P96/P96-1041.pdf